# Changing css background with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, background-color

I want to use js to change the `background` color that is set to `white` in the css. Not sure why nothing is happening.

.html

```
<body>
  <div class="invoice-box">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr class="top">
        <td colspan="2">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td class="title">
                <img src="emoji.png" width="100">
              </td>
```

.css

```
.invoice-box {
  background: white;
  max-width:800px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:30px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:24px;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#555;
```

.js

```
document.getElementById("invoice-box").style.background = "red";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery just do as sample

```
$('#element').css('background-color', '#ffffff')
```

Note: `#ffffff` = white color

Answer (score 0):

You have used `getElementById` which fetches html elements from Id, but you have defined `invoice-box` as class. Define it to `id` as well

```
<body>
<div class="invoice-box" id="invoice-box">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="top">
            <td colspan="2">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="title">
                            <img src="emoji.png" width="100">
                        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector(".invoice-box").style.background = "red";
```

How about using `querySelector`?

Answer (score 0):

you are using class and calling id in the javascript, use  instead of class